# how to read id's and connect it with name's

Tags: xslt

My XML:

```
<WorkingTime>
    <FromTime>08:00</FromTime>
    <ToTime>11:00</ToTime>
    <Name>Izpit Matematika</Name>
    <Owner>Marko Lackovic</Owner>
    <Category>
        <School Professor="111" Room="1" Subject="882" />
    </Category>
</WorkingTime>

<Professors>
    <Professor email="xxx" id="111" code="String">Name 1</Professor>
    <Professor email="xxx" id="222" code="String">Name 2</Professor>
    <Professor email="xxx" id="333" code="String">Name 3</Professor>
</Professors>
<Rooms>
    <Room id="1">IA-301</Room>
    <Room id="2">A-302</Room>
    <Room id="3">A-303</Room>
    <Room id="4">A-304</Room>
    <Room id="5">A-305</Room>
    <Room id="6">A-306</Room>

</Rooms>
<Subjects>
    <Subject id="881">Vaje</Subject>
    <Subject id="882">Kolokvij</Subject>
    <Subject id="883">Predmet</Subject>
    <Subject id="884">Izpit</Subject>
</Subjects>
```

How can I in XSLT now print `Professor`, `Room` and `Subject`.

For example:

> For Professor: Name1, for Room IA-301, and for Subject Kolokvij.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer this, but please, for the future, state your question with a little more thought..

Assuming WorkingTime is the driver/context and assuming your xml is wrapped with a "root" tag, then you would write :

```
<!-- a little shortcut variable -->
<xsl:variable name="school" select="/root/WorkingTime/Category/School"/>

<xsl:value-of select="concat('For Professor: ', 
                      /root/Professors/Professor[@id=$school/@Professor], 
                      ', for Room: ', /root/Rooms/Room[@id=$school/@Room], 
                      ', and for Subject: ', 
                      /root/Subjects/Subject[@id=$school/@Subject])"/>
```

Karl..

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up on **xsl:key** here, as this make it straight-forward to look up the records you need, and in the case of looking up records for multiple schools, more efficient.

To look up your **Professor** records, based on their **id** attribute, you would define your key as follows:

```
<xsl:key name="Professor" match="Professor" use="@id" />
```

And similarly, to look up the **Room** elements using their **id** attribute value:

```
<xsl:key name="Room" match="Room" use="@id" />
```

To use the key, assuming your were currently positioned on a **School** element (i.e within a template matching "School"), you would get the value of the **Professor** like so:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('Professor', @Professor)" />
```

So, you would probably have a template like this

```
<xsl:template match="School">
   Professor: <xsl:value-of select="key('Professor', @Professor)" />
   Room: <xsl:value-of select="key('Room', @Room)" />
</xsl:template>
```

Extending this for **Subject** is clearly straight-forward. (Note you would obviously need other code to select the **School** element in the first place, e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="//School" />`)